# Select user with no warnings last month

Tags: u-sql

I'm new at u-sql.

I have a list of users on a file, and a list of warnings by user on other file.

The files are both on datalake in csv file format.

How can i select user with no warnings?

Answer (score 1):

A worked example using `ANTISEMIJOIN` which is equivalent to `Not In` or `Not Exists` in U-SQL:

```
DECLARE @usersInputFile string = @"\input\users.csv";
DECLARE @warningsInputFile string = @"\input\warnings.csv";
DECLARE @outputFile string = @"\output\output.csv";

@users =
    EXTRACT userId int,
            userName string
    FROM @usersInputFile
    USING Extractors.Csv();

@warnings =
    EXTRACT userName string,
            warning string
    FROM @warningsInputFile
    USING Extractors.Csv();

// Get users with no warnings
@output =
    SELECT *
    FROM @users AS u
         ANTISEMIJOIN
             @warnings AS w
         ON u.userName == w.userName;


OUTPUT @output
TO @outputFile
USING Outputters.Csv(quoting : false);
```

I used these sample files:

[image: input files]

Answer (score 0):

All you need is create read the file 2 files using CSV Extractor:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/functions/operators/extractors/extractors-csv

and apply a left antisemijoin:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/statements-and-expressions/select/from/joins/antisemijoin

Comment: Is not possilbe use `where` or `not in` ?

Comment: No, u-sql not support it